# How to select data from aws athena table which is partitioned like 'year=yyyy/month=MM/date=dd/' for a given date range?

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

Athena Tables are partitioned like and same as s3 folder path

```
parent=9ab4fcca-65d8-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003/year=2020/month=4/date=17
parent=9ab4fcca-65d8-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003/year=2020/month=4/date=9
parent=0fc966a0-bba7-4c0b-a648-cff7f0332059/year=2020/month=4/date=16
parent=9ab4fcca-65d8-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003/year=2020/month=4/date=14
```

```
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `parent` string, 
  `year` int, 
  `month` tinyint, 
  `date` tinyint)
```

Now how should I form the where condition for a select query to get data for parent = "9ab4fcca-65d8-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003" from 2019-06-01 to 2020-04-31 ?

```
SELECT *  
 FROM table 
 WHERE parent = '9ab4fcca-65d8-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003' AND year >= 2019 AND year <= 2020 AND month >= 04 AND month <= 06 AND date >= 01 AND date <= 31 ;
```

But this isn't correct. Please help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Partitioning on year, month, and day separately makes it unnecessarily difficult to query tables. If you're starting out I really suggest to avoid this kind of partitioning scheme. If you can't avoid it you can still make things easier by creating the table partitions differently.

Most guides will tell you to create directory structures like `year=2020/month=4/date=1/file1`, create a table with three corresponding partition columns, and then run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` to load partitions. This works, but it's far from the best way to use Athena. `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` has atrocious performance, and partitioning like that is far from ideal.

I suggest creating directory structures that are just `2020-03-01/file1`, but if you can't, you can actually have any structure you want, `2020/03/01/file1`, `year=2020/month=4/date=1/file1`, or any other structure where there is one distinct prefix per date will work more or less equally well.

I also suggest you create tables with only one partition column: `date` (or `dt` or `day` if you want avoid quoting), typed as `DATE`, not string.

What you do then, instead of running `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` is that you use `ALTER TABLE … ADD PARTITION` or the Glue APIs directly, to add partitions. This command lets you specify the location separately from the partition column value:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD
PARTITION (day = '2020-04-01') LOCATION 's3://some-bucket/path/to/2020-04-01/'
```

The important thing here is that the partition column value doesn't have to have any relationship at all with the location, this would work equally well:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD
PARTITION (day = '2020-04-01') LOCATION 's3://some-bucket/path/to/data-for-first-of-april/'
```

For your specific case you could have:

```
PARTITIONED BY (`parent` string, `day` date)
```

and then do:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD
PARTITION (parent = '9ab4fcca-65d8-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003', day = '2020-04-17') LOCATION 's3://your-bucket/parent=9ab4fcca-65d8-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003/year=2020/month=4/date=17'
PARTITION (parent = '9ab4fcca-65d8-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003', day = '2020-04-09') LOCATION 's3://your-bucket/parent=9ab4fcca-65d8-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003/year=2020/month=4/date=9'
PARTITION (parent = '0fc966a0-bba7-4c0b-a648-cff7f0332059', day = '2020-04-16') LOCATION 's3://your-bucket/parent=0fc966a0-bba7-4c0b-a648-cff7f0332059/year=2020/month=4/date=16'
PARTITION (parent = '9ab4fcca-65d8-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003', day = '2020-04-14') LOCATION 's3://your-bucket/parent=9ab4fcca-65d8-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003/year=2020/month=4/date=14'
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is how you can use year, month and day values the come from partitions in order to select date range

```sql
SELECT col1, col2
FROM my_table 
WHERE CAST(date_parse(concat(CAST(year AS VARCHAR(4)),'-',
                             CAST(month AS VARCHAR(2)),'-',
                             CAST(day AS VARCHAR(2))
                             ), '%Y-%m-%d') as DATE) 
BETWEEN DATE '2019-06-01' AND DATE '2020-04-31'
```

You can add additional filter statements as needed)

Comment: Thanks !! This works but its taking more time to scan, is there any improvements possible or better approach? Is it an effective approach?

Comment: If you have a lot of partitions one explanation for why this is slower could be that instead of Athena asking the Glue Catalog API to filter the partitions it needs to do it in a later stage. The Glue API can do filtering with comparisons of individual columns, but when you combine them together with functions like this that is not possible and I assume that all partition metadata is loaded from Glue, all partition locations are listed on S3, and only later are partitions pruned. All those extra S3 operations could hurt query performance significantly. Avoid functions on partition columns.

Comment: I have exactly the same suspicions as @Theo, i.e Athena loads meta information about all partitions, and only then does filtering. Although using partitions in this way in `WHERE` clause wouldn’t increase scanned data, you don’t utilise push down predicates for filtering partitions because of casting, concatenation etc.